# How to call selfdestruct in my other contract on the same tx I deploy my new contract with Truffle?

Tags: contract-deployment, truffle-deployment, selfdestruct

Title says it all. I have a contract already deployed on the blockchain. Unfortunately I need to do some changes to it so will need to re-deploy it, and the previous one will become useless. I'd like to call `selfdestruct()` on it to save some gas costs on the re-deployment of the new one, but not sure how to do it. Should I code it in the migration file that I will use to deploy the new contract? It currently looks like this:

```
const MainContract = artifacts.require("MainContract");
const myLibrary = artifacts.require("myLibrary");

async function doDeploy(deployer) {
    await deployer.deploy(myLibrary);
    await deployer.link(myLibrary, MainContract);
    await deployer.deploy(MainContract);
}


module.exports = (deployer, network) => {
    deployer.then(async () => {
        await doDeploy(deployer);
    });
};
```

Thanks

Comment: I think it does not work like that. There is natively no way to deploy a new contract and call another function (directly) of a contract in the same transaction

Comment: Your new deployed contract should call the selfdestruct function of the old contract in its constructor, but I don’t think that it has the permission to do that. And after the London upgrade u don’t get gas back (not 100% sure about it)

Comment: Hey that's actually a great idea. Indeed the new address wouldn't have premission to call selfdestruct in the other contract (I'm using a modifier), but if I deploy the new contract with the same owner of the other one, and then call `selfdestruct()` with `delegatecall` in the constructor I think it should work, right? Thanks!

Comment: I’m 99% sure it does not work like that, I don’t remember exactly how delegate works :) anyway you need to try such a thing on a test net or locally first